# swift constant inferred to have type () which may be unexpected

Tags: swift, concurrency

I have the following code:

```swift
public func test_mutex() async
{
   let mutex = Mutex()
   async let a = mutex.exclusive("a") { await Tasks.after(ms: 300) {print("a")}}
   async let b = mutex.exclusive("b") { await Tasks.after(ms: 200) {print("b")}}
   async let c = mutex.exclusive("c") { await Tasks.after(ms: 100) {print("c")}}
   _ = await [a, b, c]
}
```

and am getting three of this error:

```
Constant 'a' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected
```

however - the entire point is that I'm testing a function which returns nothing - I have another test that tests a function that returns something - ie () is NOT unexpected at all - and I can't just make the thing return something.

how do I get rid of the warning?  - or how do I otherwise cause three async things to happen *in parallel* and then await them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I otherwise cause three async things to happen in parallel and then await them

You use a *task group*, as explained in the Structured Concurrency video.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/3814991-withtaskgroup?changes=__1

Each call to the group's `async` method is an opportunity for you to call an asynchronous method to be run in parallel. When all calls are finished, the `await` on the task finishes and we proceed.

Alternatively I suppose you could declare the type of your a, b, and c to be `()` as suggested by the FixIt. But that seems rather a cheap approach. Better to do this properly.

So for example I made up a thing that behaves like I imagine your Mutex might behave:

```
class Waiter {
    func go(after:TimeInterval,  f: @escaping ()->()) async {
        await withUnsafeContinuation { (c:UnsafeContinuation<Void,Never>) in
            DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline:.now()+after) {
                f()
                c.resume()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then this compiles and runs fine:

```
    let w = Waiter()
    async let x:() = w.go(after: 1) { print(1) }
    async let y:() = w.go(after: 1) { print(2) }
    async let z:() = w.go(after: 1) { print(3) }
    let _ = [await x, await y, await z]
```

However, I still think a task group is nicer.

```
    let w = Waiter()
    print("start")
    await withTaskGroup(of:Void.self) { group in
        for i in [1,2,3] {
            group.async {
                await w.go(after:1) { print(i) }
            }
        }
    }
    print("done")
```

Comment: sorry - I'm probably being stupid - but I couldn't see how to use task group in this case?
and as for declaring them all void - tried that - but it didn't make the warning go away :(

Comment: Oh, okay, give me some time, I'll write out the code for you. I'm just in the middle of downloading the next beta so it will take me a while to get to this. — However, I'm not sure what a mutex is, actually, so maybe this is trickier. My answer was based on just the one sentence you asked: to request parallel execution, use a task group.

Comment: Can you provide the Mutex code? Otherwise I guess I could just make something up.

Comment: Did you try the Fix-It?

Comment: there was no fix-it - but  you gave me the real solution - which is just the 
     async let a: () = whatever

I had tried
     async let a: Void = whatever

thanks.    This is in a test - so I think that's a lot cleaner than all the code associated with the task group.

Comment: Fine by me! It's early days on this stuff, glad to see folks experimenting.